# Listview is not showing the button properly based on condition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

[image]

[image]

Here are two screens. The condition is when order status is **Canceled** than don't need to show the edit button else edit button should be display. The inconsistency is that in some of the Item of cancel it is not showing while in some of it's showing. The Fragment is same. You can compare both screens. Here is my code :

```
package com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.IconTextView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.ApplicationController;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.ApplicationInfo;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.R;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.activity.NavDrawerActivity;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.dialog.ValidationDialog;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.fragment.OrderFragment;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.object.OrdersObject;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.util.AndroidUtils;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.util.Constants;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.util.SharedPrefrenceUtils;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.webservice.WebServiceResponseListener;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.webservice.factory.WebServiceRequestExecutorFactory;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.webservice.json.RequestClass;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.webservice.json.request.DataObject;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.webservice.json.request.Request;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.webservice.json.request.RequestCommand;
import com.logisticaforce.logisticaforce.webservice.json.response.Response;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OrdersObject> implements WebServiceResponseListener {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<OrdersObject> mList;
    LinearLayout linearLayout,layout;
    private OrdersObject myitem = null;
    private OrderFragment orderFragObject;
    TextView textView;
    private List<Integer> view = new ArrayList<>();
    public OrderAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<OrdersObject> mList,OrderFragment orderFragObject){
        super(mContext, R.layout.activity_orders, mList);
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mList = mList;
        this.orderFragObject=orderFragObject;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public OrdersObject getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder{
        private LinearLayout orderMain,orderTitleMain;
        private TextView orderName;
        private TextView orderRate;
        private TextView orderTitle;
        private TextView orderId;
        private TextView orderBy;
        private TextView orderStatus;
        private TextView orderCreateDate;
        private TextView orderDeliveryDate;
        private LinearLayout collapseImage;
        private LinearLayout getLayout;
        private IconTextView btnOrderEdit;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        OrdersObject item = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder mViewHolder;
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.activity_orders,parent,false);
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            mViewHolder.orderName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_name_lbl);
            mViewHolder.orderRate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_rate);

            mViewHolder.orderTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_title);
            mViewHolder.orderId = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.orderIdLbl);
            mViewHolder.orderBy = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_by_lbl);
            mViewHolder.orderStatus = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_status_lbl);
            mViewHolder.orderCreateDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_crdate);
            mViewHolder.orderDeliveryDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_deldate);
            mViewHolder.orderMain = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.orderMain);
            mViewHolder.orderTitleMain=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.orderTitleMain);
            mViewHolder.getLayout=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.drpDownViewContainer);
            mViewHolder.btnOrderEdit=(IconTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnOrderEdit);
            textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleLbl);

            mViewHolder.btnOrderEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    myitem = (OrdersObject)view.getTag();
                    if(null!= SharedPrefrenceUtils.getString(mContext,"openOrderId")){
                        ValidationDialog.showDialog(orderFragObject.getChildFragmentManager(),R.string.fAlreadyOpen);
                    }else{
                        sendEditOrderRequest(myitem);
                    }
                }
            });

            mViewHolder.collapseImage = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.orderMain);
            mViewHolder.collapseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer id =(Integer) v.getTag();
                    if(view.contains(id)){
                        view.remove(id);
                    }else{
                        view.add(id);
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        }else{
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        //Expanding and Collapsing
        mViewHolder.collapseImage.setTag(position);
        if(view.contains(position)){
            mViewHolder.getLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            mViewHolder.getLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        mViewHolder.btnOrderEdit.setTag(item);
        mViewHolder.orderName.setText(item.getOrderName());
        mViewHolder.orderRate.setText("$"+String.valueOf(item.getOrderPrice()));

        mViewHolder.orderTitle.setText(item.getOrderTitle());
        mViewHolder.orderId.setText(String.valueOf(item.getOrderId()));
        mViewHolder.orderBy.setText(item.getOrderBy());
        mViewHolder.orderStatus.setText(item.getOrderStatus());
        mViewHolder.orderCreateDate.setText((item.getOrderCreateDate()));
        mViewHolder.orderDeliveryDate.setText(String.valueOf(item.getOrderDeliveryDate()));

        //Setting Theme


        mViewHolder.orderRate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(ApplicationInfo.getSdfColor(mContext)));



        if(item.getOrderStatus().equals("Canceled")){
            mViewHolder.orderMain.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.canceled));
            mViewHolder.orderName.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            mViewHolder.orderTitleMain.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.canceled1));
        }else{
            mViewHolder.orderMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(ApplicationInfo.getPdColor(mContext)));
            mViewHolder.orderName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(ApplicationInfo.getPlfColor(mContext)));
            mViewHolder.orderTitleMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(ApplicationInfo.getPlColor(mContext)));

            if(ApplicationController.allowPlacedOrderEditing.equals("Y"))
            {
                mViewHolder.btnOrderEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                mViewHolder.btnOrderEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

       return convertView;
    }

    public void sendEditOrderRequest(OrdersObject item){
        Request rq = new Request();
        RequestCommand rc=new RequestCommand();
        rc.setId("R1");
        rc.setParserVersion("1");
        RequestClass rt1=new RequestClass();
        rt1.setBatchSize(Constants.BATCH_SIZE);
        rt1.setName("manageOrder");
        rt1.setStartRow("0");
        List<DataObject> attr=new ArrayList<>();
        DataObject do1=new DataObject();
        do1.setName("action");
        do1.setValue("reopenOrder");
        attr.add(do1);
        DataObject do2=new DataObject();
        do2.setName("openOrderId");
        if(null!=SharedPrefrenceUtils.getString(mContext,"openOrderId")){
            do2.setValue(SharedPrefrenceUtils.getString(mContext,"openOrderId"));
        }else{
            do2.setValue("");
        }
        attr.add(do2);
        DataObject do3=new DataObject();
        do3.setName("customerOrderId");
        do3.setValue(String.valueOf(item.getOrderId()));
        attr.add(do3);
        DataObject do4=new DataObject();
        do4.setName("serviceLocationId");
        do4.setValue(SharedPrefrenceUtils.getString(mContext, "serviceLocationId"));
        attr.add(do4);
        rt1.setParams(attr);
        rt1.setResultAttributes(null);
        rt1.setRequestParam(rc);
        rq.setRequest(rc);
        Gson gs=new Gson();
        String jsonString=new Gson().toJson(rq);
        Log.i("TAG2", "Request String Edit Order : " + jsonString);

        WebServiceRequestExecutorFactory.getWebServiceExecutor(mContext, rq, this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebServiceResponse(Response resp, String tag) {
        if(null!=resp){
            List result=resp.getResponse().getCmd();
            if(AndroidUtils.getResultParams(result, "name")!=null) {
                if(AndroidUtils.getResultParams(result,"name").equals("manageOrder")){
                    if (AndroidUtils.getResultParams(result, "result").equals("OK")) {
                        SharedPrefrenceUtils.putString(mContext,"openOrderId",String.valueOf(myitem.getOrderId()));
                        ((NavDrawerActivity)orderFragObject.getActivity()).displayView(4);
                    }else if (AndroidUtils.getResultParams(result, "result").equals("ERROR")) {
                        ValidationDialog.showDialog(orderFragObject.getChildFragmentManager(), R.string.fCommonError);
                    }
            }
        }else{
                ValidationDialog.showDialog(orderFragObject.getChildFragmentManager(), R.string.fCommonError);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you right then you want to hide the edit button if order is in canceled status. If so then you should move this code out of the `if-else` block.

```
if(ApplicationController.allowPlacedOrderEditing.equals("Y"))
{
    mViewHolder.btnOrderEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
    mViewHolder.btnOrderEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Or simply this

```
if(item.getOrderStatus().equals("Canceled")){
    mViewHolder.btnOrderEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mViewHolder.orderMain.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.canceled));
    mViewHolder.orderName.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    mViewHolder.orderTitleMain.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.canceled1));
}else{
    mViewHolder.btnOrderEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mViewHolder.orderMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(ApplicationInfo.getPdColor(mContext)));
    mViewHolder.orderName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(ApplicationInfo.getPlfColor(mContext)));
    mViewHolder.orderTitleMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(ApplicationInfo.getPlColor(mContext)));
}
```